# Solution of a partial differential equation.

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Find $u=u(x,y)$ satisfying
$$\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = 6xy, \,\,\,u(0,y) = y, \,\,\,\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(1,y)=0.$$

I have tried by laplace transformation $$\displaystyle s^2\bar{u}(s,y)-su(0,y)-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,y) = \frac{6y}{s^2}
\,\,\,\Longrightarrow\,\,\,
\bar{u}(s,y)=sy +\frac{ 6y}{s^2}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,y).$$

Please tell me how to proceed.

Answer (score 7):

Integrating twice with respect to $x$ we obtain that
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=6xy\quad\Longrightarrow\quad u(x,y)=f_1(y)+x\,f_2(y)+x^3y.
$$
Incorporating the initial data we get that
$$
y=u(0,y)=f_1(y),
$$
and
$$
0=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(1,y)=f_2(y)+3y \quad\text{thus}\quad f_2(y)=-3y.
$$
Finally the unique solution of the initial value problem is
$$
u(x,y)=y-3xy+x^3y.
$$

Answer (score 4):

You may not use Laplace transform for solving boundary value problems, since you have no information of $u_x(0,y)$. Indeed, this problem can be solved by direct integration with respect to to $x$. Precisely, if: $$u_{xx} = 6xy,$$ then by using partial integration:

$$u_x = 3x^2y + f(y) \Rightarrow u(x,y) = x^3 y+ x f(y) + g(y).$$

Now apply the boundary conditions in order to get the arbitrary functions $f(y)$ and $g(y)$.

Cheers!